# Angular testing: pasar valor de variable del test al servicio

Tags: angular, unittest, karma-jasmine

Debo probar un servicio de Angular pero no comprendo como puedo asignar el valor de la variable en el servicio para poder entrar a las condiciones de los if, por ejemplo desde el test quiero asignarle valores a `environment.sessionRewardStore` y a `environment.sessionStoreElegibilityKeys` pero no logro hacerlo, mi servicio: (edito para subir el codigo completo del metodo getPurchasableRewards)

```
  public async getPurchasableRewards() {
    let userStores: RewardStore[] = [];
    await this.sessionmApi.getUserRewardStores().then((r) => {      
      if (Array.isArray(r)) {
        if (environment.sessionmRewardStore) {
          userStores = r.filter((s) => {
            return s.id === environment.sessionmRewardStore;
          });
        } else {    
          userStores = r.filter((s) => {
            return s.eligibility_models.find((e) => environment.sessionmStoreEligibilityKeys.includes(e));
          });
        }
      }
    });
    if (Array.isArray(userStores) && userStores.length > 0) {
      return this.sessionmApi.getRewardStoreOffers(userStores).then((rewards: IPurchasableReward[]) => {
        return this.store.dispatch({
          type: AppStateActions.PURCHASABLE_REWARDS,
          payload: rewards
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Mi test:

```
fit('should getPurchasableRewards return .....', (doneFn) => {
    const mock = {
      type: AppStateActions.PURCHASABLE_REWARDS,
      payload: MockIPurchasableReward
    };
 
    const spysgetValue = spyOn(service['sessionmApi'], 'getUserRewardStores').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(MockRewardStoreArray));

    //Aqui intento asignar el valor:
    environment.sessionmRewardStore='STORE-1'

    service.getPurchasableRewards().then((data) => {
      console.log('DATA PP:', data)
      doneFn();
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
      console.log('error', err)
    })
  });
```

Archivo environment original que usa el servicio: environment.ts, este importa una interfaz con los nombres de todas las variables:

```
import { environment as coreEnv, IxxxEnvironment } from '@xxx/files';
const env = {};

export const environment: IxxxEnvironment | any = coreEnv || env;
```

yo me cree uno que pense podría utilizar para reemplazar las variables que me interesa usar: environmentMock

```
import { IxxxEnvironment, abc } from '@xxx/files';
export const environmentMock: IxxxEnvironment | any = {
  apiBaseUrl: 'https://abc.com',
  sessionmStoreEligibilityKeys: ["public", "user_affiliation"],
  sessionmRewardStore:'ABC'
};
```

Comment: Quizá no entiendo tu duda, pero entiendo que lo que quieres es ejecutar el test variando el valor de `MockRewardStoreArray`.

Comment: En el servicio hay unos if, para entrar a esos se revisan unas variables en el servicio: environment.sessionmRewardStore y environment.sessionmStoreEligibilityKeys y dependiendo de eso se hace un proceso en el servicio, necesito enviarle valores a esas variables para comprobar que funciona pero no logro hacerlo :(

Comment: De dónde sale esa variable `environment`? Porque para hacer lo que quieres debería mockearla e inyectarla en tu función

Comment: esa variable en el servicio sale de un import de un archivo de configuracion: Import {environment} from 'archivo', ¿como deberia mockear esa variable?

Comment: Podrías agregar el código completo? `getPurchasableRewards` esto es un servicio de Angular o es una simple función? De eso depende cómo se mockearia. (Puedes hacer click en [edit])

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo edite en la publicación, esas variables en el servicio vienen de un import de un archivo de configuración

Comment: Creo que te faltó agregar los imports. De todas formas puedes leer cómo se mockean imports con jasmine aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240469/how-can-i-mock-the-imports-of-an-es6-module

Comment: Gracias Andres, ya lo vi pero este es un archivo de configuracion solamente con un objeto y sus propiedades o variables, lo he intentado pero creo que no es igual :(, seguire intentando.

Comment: Podrías agregar a tu pregunta el archivo en si por favor

Comment: Claro, esta hecho y nuevamente gracias

Answer (score 1):

Una solución podría ser usar [inversión de dependencias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_inversi%C3%B3n_de_la_dependencia) en tu función y enviarle como parámetro el objeto config de configuración.

Teniendo así la posibilidad de variar la implementación del mismo para tus casos de prueba.

El código podría quedar así:

```javascript
public async getPurchasableRewards(environment) { // Lo recibimos como parámetro
    let userStores: RewardStore[] = [];
    await this.sessionmApi.getUserRewardStores().then((r) => {      
      if (Array.isArray(r)) {
        if (environment.sessionmRewardStore) {
          userStores = r.filter((s) => {
            return s.id === environment.sessionmRewardStore;
          });
        } else {    
          userStores = r.filter((s) => {
            return s.eligibility_models.find((e) => environment.sessionmStoreEligibilityKeys.includes(e));
          });
        }
      }
    });
    if (Array.isArray(userStores) && userStores.length > 0) {
      return this.sessionmApi.getRewardStoreOffers(userStores).then((rewards: IPurchasableReward[]) => {
        return this.store.dispatch({
          type: AppStateActions.PURCHASABLE_REWARDS,
          payload: rewards
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Ahora bien, hay que tener en cuenta la forma en la que usamos la función `getPurchasableRewards`, ya que ahora cada vez que la usemos debemos proveerle una implementación de `environments`.

Para tu test esto sería:

`test.js`

```javascript
it('should getPurchasableRewards return .....', (doneFn) => {
    const mock = {
      type: AppStateActions.PURCHASABLE_REWARDS,
      payload: MockIPurchasableReward
    };
 
    const spysgetValue = spyOn(service['sessionmApi'], 'getUserRewardStores').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(MockRewardStoreArray));

    //Declaramos environment aquí
    const environment = {}
    environment.sessionmRewardStore = 'STORE-1'
    environment.sessionStoreElegibilityKeys = ["public", "user_affiliation"]

    service.getPurchasableRewards(environment) // Le pasamos la variable a nuestra función
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('DATA PP:', data)
        doneFn();
      })
      .catch((err) =>{
        console.log('error', err)
      })
  });
```

Y para el caso de usar la función realmente en tu app:

```javascript
import { environment } from "la/ruta/a/environment";

getPurchasableRewards(environment)
   .then(res => console.log(res))
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Si bien quizás la inversión de dependencias se ve más a menudo en el constructor de una clase por ejemplo, esta es una solución válida para que tu función sea más fácil de testear.

---

EDIT:

### Solución completa

Si la función es parte de un método de una clase podríamos hacer uso de la inversión de dependencia sin tener que pasarle la variable como parámetro a la función en sí.

Ejemplo:

Si bien no está en tu pregunta, supongo que la función `getPurchasableRewards` es un método de una clase. Por lo que la inyección de dependencia puede pasar a nivel de instanciación de la clase.

`rewards.service.ts`

```javascript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RewardsService {
  private environment: environment;

  constructor(environment: environment) { // Gracias a esto podemos inyectar distintas implementaciones de la configuración.
    this.environment = environment;
  }

  async getPurchasableRewards(): Promise<any> {
    ...
    // Acá usamos environment normalmente
    if (this.environment.sessionmRewardStore) {} // Importante notar que usamos this.environment ya que es una propiedad de nuestra clase
    ...
  }
}
```

Y para el test, usamos la inyección de dependencias que provee angular:

`rewards.service.spec.ts`

```javascript
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RewardsService } from './rewards.service';

describe('RewardsService', () => {
  let service: RewardsService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const environmentMock = { sessionRewardStore: "", sessionStoreElegibilityKeys: ["public", "user_affiliation"] /* aquí agregarías las propiedades y métodos que necesites */ };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        RewardsService,
        { provide: 'environment', useValue: environmentMock } // Acá le decimos al test que use el mock que creamos arriba
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(RewardsService);
  });

it('should getPurchasableRewards return .....', (doneFn) => {
    service.getPurchasableRewards().then((data) => { // Ejecutamos la función sabiendo que está usando el mock que le pasamos
      console.log('DATA PP:', data)
      doneFn();
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
      console.log('error', err)
    })
  });

});
```